# How I can use Poly retry library for. Net Framework and db context

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am using .Net Framework 4.7.1 and using edmx file and db context.

How can I use Poly retry library when selecting reorcds or connection with database?

I found many example for .net core but unable to find for db context.

i want to make a general policy for connection retry in this get

```
    public sqweb2Entities WebEntities

    {
        get

        {
            if (null == _WebEntities)
            {

                _WebEntities = new sqweb2Entities();
                LogHelper.LogInfo(string.Format("Connecting to Web DB: {0}", _WebEntities.Database.Connection.ConnectionString), LogHelper.Categories.SQService);
            }

            if (_WebEntities.Database.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                _WebEntities.Database.Connection.Open();


            return _WebEntities;

        }
    }
```

Thanks!!

https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki

Comment: To do what? Retry what code? The library docs already show how you can retry any kind of code, with `somePolicy.Execute(()=>someMethod());`

Comment: How those samples don't apply to your case?

Comment: I have modified my question

Comment: Properties are properties. They hold data. What you posted should be a method. There's no EF code anyway, but there *is* some very suspicious code trying to fiddle with a connection and far, far worse, live it open. This *guarantees* errors, by keeping transactions and acquired locks alive, blocking other connections. Fix the code instead of retrying it.  Retrying bad data access code only makes things *worse* by increasing blocking and deadlocks